# Problems with npm (Jessie): Illegal instruction

Tags: raspbian

I'm trying to use `npm` on my Raspberry Pi under Debian testing (Jessie). When I perform a command like:

```
 npm install -dnpm express
```

I get the error message:

```
Illegal instruction
```

This seems to be an error in the package. I tried to install the current version from http://nodejs.org/ manually, but I get the same message. What does that mean and what can I do?

Comment: Shouldn't the command be npm install -dnpm express? or just npm install express? or most likely sudo npm install -g express

Comment: @SteveRobillard Absolutely, I corrected that, this error is the same.

Comment: Ths seems to be a known bug called the illegal exception bomb. This site claims to habe a solution http://www.schrankmonster.de/2014/03/22/install-nodejs-npm-raspberrypi-illegal-instruction-error-messages/ but I have not tried it myself.

Comment: It seemed to work at first, but now I have the error again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two commands will install a recent ARM architecture supporting version of node and npm. Make sure to start a new session or use the `bash` command to use the new node and npm path variables.

```
wget http://node-arm.herokuapp.com/node_latest_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i node_latest_armhf.deb
```